# Find entry between two entries in a php variable

Tags: php, html, mysqli, find, strpos

I have a php variable that looks like this q1q32q1qq2q14q2qq3q16q3q. The logic of this variable is that an entry starts with for instance q1q and ends with q1q and in between those two entries there is a number, in this example 32. What I want is to write a code that finds the number in between given that you know q1q. This is what I started to write

```
strpos($participants, "q" . $_SESSION["UserID"] . "q")
```

In accordance with the above example $_SESSION["UserID"] is equal to 1 and $participants is the variable containing q1q32q1qq2q14q2qq3q16q3q. Any ideas on how to complete my code?

Comment: `$arr = explode("q1q", "q1q32q1qq2q14q2qq3q16q3q");` // result will be in `$arr[1]` and in `$arr[2]` will be the rest of string `q2q14q2qq3q16q3q`?

Comment: @pes502 what happend to array element [0] ?

Comment: @Naruto its empty, because before start of string `q1q` is not any other character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `preg_match`

```
$str = 'q1q32q1qq2q14q2qq3q16q3q';
$word1 = 'q1q';
$word2 = 'q1q';
preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $str, $match);

print_r($match); //$match[1] will have desired output
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => q1q32q1q
    [1] => 32
)
```

you can try with `strpos` and `substr` but it quite lengthy
see below example:

```
echo substr($str, (strpos($str, $word1) + strlen($word1)), (strpos($str, $word2, 1) - strlen($word2))); //output: 32
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to buffer read the php file and add condition if string variable is found in the file, then manipulate it as you need
 I don't think is any other way